# keeps adding margin after every sql result

Tags: php, html, css

I have a big problem and i hope someone can help me,
i created a platform where admin's can respond to tickets but when a ticket is recieved it automaticly generates margin-top of the results body. So when a new ticket is recieved it addes more margin. I've added screenshots to make it more understandable. Sorry for the messy code :o i always optimize & make it more secure when i approach the final stage :)

Ticket total overview
`

```html
<?php
//starten van sessie 
session_start();
//declaratie van sessie variabelen
$status = $_SESSION['account_status'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("Location: ../index.php");    
}else {

    if ($status == '1'){
//admin waarde ophalen
require('../procces_files/admin_waarde_ophalen.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>-</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="../css/style.scss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<header class="header">
  <a href="" class="logo">Support</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="index.php"> Open tickets</a></li>
  <?php if($admin2 == 1) { ?><li><a href="../procces_files/gesloten_tickets.php">Gesloten tickets</a></li><?php }
            if($admin2 == 0) { ?><li><a href="../ticket_aanmaken/index.php">Ticket aanmaken</a></li><?php }
            if($admin2 == 0) { ?><li><a href="../faq/index.php">FAQ</a></li><?php   }?>
            <li><a href="../procces_files/uitloggen.php">Uitloggen</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
<body>
<div id="lichaam2">
    <img id="flexa-logo3" src="../img/flexa.png" alt="flexamedia logo"/>
 <?php
//if user is a 'admin'
    if($admin2 == 1) {

        //retrieving tickets 'telefonie'
        ?><section id="cat-container"><div id="telefonie"><?php
        //file voor overzicht tickets alle gebruikers
        require('../procces_files/ticket_overzicht_telefonie.php');
        ?></div><?php


        //retrieving tickets 'website-onderhoud'
        ?><div id="website"><?php
        //file voor overzicht tickets alle gebruikers
        require('../procces_files/ticket_overzicht_website.php');
        ?></div><?php


        //retrieving tickets 'ICT-helpdesk'
        ?><div id="ict"><?php
        //file voor overzicht tickets alle gebruikers
        require('../procces_files/ticket_overzicht_ict.php');
        ?></div></section><?php
    }
    //if user is a 'normal user'
    if($admin2 == 0) {
        ?><div id="blok-container2"><?php
        //file voor overzicht tickets per gebruiker
    require('../procces_files/ticket_overzicht_per_gebruiker.php');
    ?></div><?php
    }

?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php }else {
    header('location: ../procces_files/account_niet_geactiveerd.php');
}} ?>
```

require code for ticket retrieving 'telefonie'

```
<?php
//checkt of een ticket recent is verwijderd, zoja? laat dan tekst zien
if (!isset($_SESSION['message'])){
    $_SESSION['message'] = ' ';
};
if ($_SESSION['message'] == 'Ticket verwijderd') {
?><script>alert('U heeft de ticket verwijderd');</script> <?php
$_SESSION['message'] = ' ';
}
//database configuratie file
require('dbconfig.php');

//admin waarde ophalen
require('../procces_files/admin_waarde_ophalen.php');
//beveiliging dat voorkomt dat 'geen admin' gebruikers dit bestand kunnen uitvoeren en tickets kunnen verwijderen
if ($admin2 == '1') {


$username = $_SESSION['username'];

//verwerking ophalen tickets per gebruiker en voor elke afdeling
$showTicketsQuery = "SELECT * FROM tickets order by id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $showTicketsQuery) or die(mysqli_error($result));

?>
<h1>Telefonie</h1>
<table>
<div class='ticket'><tr><th><b>Ticket NR</b></th><th><b>Naam:</b></th><th><b>Onderwerp</b></th><th><b>Debiteur</b></th><th><b>Acties</b></th></tr>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{  
    if ($row['status'] == '0'){
       if ($row['afdeling'] == 'Telefonie'){
    //een table met ticket resultaten
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['naam'] . "</td><td>" . $row['onderwerp'] . "</td><td>" . $row['maker']   . "</td><td>" . '<a class="naarticket" onclick="test" href="../procces_files/ticket_verwijder_procces.php?del=' . $row['id'] . '">del</a>' . '<br><a class="naarticket" href="../procces_files/ticket_overley.php?view=' . $row['id'] . '"' . ';>inzien</a>' . '<br><a class="naarticket" href="../procces_files/ticket_status_update.php?sluit=' . $row['id'] . '"' . ';>sluit</a>' . "</td></tr><BR><BR></div>";
}
}}
?>
</table>
<?php
}else {
    echo '<h2 style="color:red;">ACCES DENIED <br>Deze site is beveiligd tegen dit soort dingen :)</h2>';
}
?>
```

retrieving tickets 'website

```
<?php
//checkt of een ticket recent is verwijderd, zoja? laat dan tekst zien
if (!isset($_SESSION['message'])){
    $_SESSION['message'] = ' ';
};
if ($_SESSION['message'] == 'Ticket verwijderd') {
?><script>alert('U heeft de ticket verwijderd');</script> <?php
$_SESSION['message'] = ' ';
}
//database configuratie file
require('dbconfig.php');

//admin waarde ophalen
require('../procces_files/admin_waarde_ophalen.php');
//beveiliging dat voorkomt dat 'geen admin' gebruikers dit bestand kunnen uitvoeren en tickets kunnen verwijderen
if ($admin2 == '1') {

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

//verwerking ophalen tickets per gebruiker en voor elke afdeling
$showTicketsQuery = "SELECT * FROM tickets order by id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $showTicketsQuery) or die(mysqli_error($result));

?>
<h1>Website Onderhoud</h1>
<table>
<div class='ticket'><tr><th><b>Ticket NR</b></th><th><b>Naam:</b></th><th><b>Onderwerp</b></th><th><b>Debiteur</b></th><th><b>Acties</b></th></tr>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{  
    if ($row['status'] == '0'){
       if ($row['afdeling'] == 'Website-onderhoud'){
    //een table met ticket resultaten
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['naam'] . "</td><td>" . $row['onderwerp'] . "</td><td>" . $row['maker']   . "</td><td>" . '<a class="naarticket" onclick="test" href="../procces_files/ticket_verwijder_procces.php?del=' . $row['id'] . '">del</a>' . '<br><a class="naarticket" href="../procces_files/ticket_overley.php?view=' . $row['id'] . '"' . ';>inzien</a>' . '<br><a class="naarticket" href="../procces_files/ticket_status_update.php?sluit=' . $row['id'] . '"' . ';>sluit</a>' . "</td></tr><BR><BR></div>";
}
}}
?>
</table>
<?php

}else {
    echo '<h2 style="color:red;">ACCES DENIED <br>Deze site is beveiligd tegen dit soort dingen :)</h2>';
}
?>
```

Retrieving tickets 'ict'

```
<?php
//checkt of een ticket recent is verwijderd, zoja? laat dan tekst zien
if (!isset($_SESSION['message'])){
    $_SESSION['message'] = ' ';
};
if ($_SESSION['message'] == 'Ticket verwijderd') {
?><script>alert('U heeft de ticket verwijderd');</script> <?php
$_SESSION['message'] = ' ';
}
//database configuratie file
require('dbconfig.php');

//admin waarde ophalen
require('../procces_files/admin_waarde_ophalen.php');
//beveiliging dat voorkomt dat 'geen admin' gebruikers dit bestand kunnen uitvoeren en tickets kunnen verwijderen
if ($admin2 == '1') {


$username = $_SESSION['username'];

//verwerking ophalen tickets per gebruiker en voor elke afdeling
$showTicketsQuery = "SELECT * FROM tickets order by id DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $showTicketsQuery) or die(mysqli_error($result));

?>
<h1>ICT-Helpdesk</h1>
<table>
<div class='ticket'><tr><th><b>Ticket NR</b></th><th><b>Naam:</b></th><th><b>Onderwerp</b></th><th><b>Debiteur</b></th><th><b>Acties</b></th></tr>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{  
    if ($row['status'] == '0'){
       if ($row['afdeling'] == 'ICT-Helpdesk'){
    //een table met ticket resultaten
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['naam'] . "</td><td>" . $row['onderwerp'] . "</td><td>" . $row['maker']   . "</td><td>" . '<a class="naarticket" onclick="test" href="../procces_files/ticket_verwijder_procces.php?del=' . $row['id'] . '">del</a>' . '<br><a class="naarticket" href="../procces_files/ticket_overley.php?view=' . $row['id'] . '"' . ';>inzien</a>' . '<br><a class="naarticket" href="../procces_files/ticket_status_update.php?sluit=' . $row['id'] . '"' . ';>sluit</a>' . "</td></tr><BR><BR></div>";
}
}}
?>
</table>
<?php


}else {
    echo '<h2 style="color:red;">ACCES DENIED <br>Deze site is beveiligd tegen dit soort dingen :)</h2>';
}
?>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: none;
}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    body {
      background-color: #2d3e56;
      }
    
    #blok-container2 {
      background-color: #2d3e56;
       position: absolute;
       margin-top: 300px;
       width: 90%;
       min-height: 400px;
       color: white;
       margin-left: 20px;

    } 
    .naarticket {
      color: white;
    }
   
    #blok-container-aanmaakform {
      background-color: #2d3e56;
      margin-top: 560px;
      width: 100%;
    } 
    #blok-container-overview {
      background-color: #2d3e56;
      margin-top: 720px;
      width: 100%;
      color: white;
    } 
    #blok-container-faq {
      background-color: #2d3e56;
      margin-top: 180px;
      width: 100%;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    } 
    #blok-container-admin-tickets {
    background-color: #2d3e56;
       position: absolute;
       margin-top: 120px;
       width: 90%;
       min-height: 400px;
       color: white;
    }

    .textfield {
     
      width: 90%;
      height: 200px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      background-color:#2d3e56 ;
      border-right: none;
      border-left: none;
      border-top: none;
      border-bottom: solid grey 1px;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    .verwerkknoppen {
      margin-top: 5px;
      color: white;
    }

    #flex-container {
      display: flex;
      border-bottom: solid grey 1px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
    #bijlageinfo {
      float: right;
      overflow:scroll; 
      height:85px;
    }
    #ticketinfos {
      width: 320px;
    }
    form {
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
    #overview-reply-textarea {
      width: 90%;
      height: 50px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      background-color:#2d3e56 ;
      border-right: none;
      border-left: none;
      border-top: none;
      border-bottom: solid grey 1px;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    #berichten {
      overflow:scroll; height:300px;
    }

    .velden {
      width: 90%;
      margin-left: 10px;
      background-color:#2d3e56 ;
      border-right: none;
      border-left: none;
      border-top: none;
      border-bottom: solid grey 1px;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 24px;
      
    }
    #blok-container {
      width: 350px;
     
    }
    
    #blok-container-register {
      width: 350px;
      margin-top: -40px;
       
      
    }
    #flexa-logo {
      width: 150px;
      justify-content: center;
      justify-self: center;
    }
    #flexa-logo-reg {
      width: 150px;
      justify-content: center;
      justify-self: center;
      margin-top: 200px;
      
    }
    #flexa-logo3 {
      display: none;
    }
    #lichaam {
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 500px;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    #lichaam2 {
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 30px;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    
    }
    .voorwaarde-tekst {
      color: white;
      
    }
    .voorwaarde-link {
      color: white;
      text-decoration-line: underline !important;
    }
    .submitknop {
      background-color: grey;
      color: white;
      width: 140px;
      height: 50px;
      border: none;
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-left: 100px;
      margin-top: 2px;

    }
    .aanmeldtekst {
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }
#register {
  color: white;
  text-decoration-line: underline !important;
}
table, th, td {
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: solid grey 1px;



}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  
}
th {
  text-align: left;
  
}
#tabel {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

  //deactivatie scrollbars

#ticket2::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
#berichten::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
  


  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    body {
      background-color: #2d3e56;
   
    }
      #alletickers {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 400px;
      }
    
    #blok-container2 {
      background-color: #2d3e56;
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: 270px;
      width: 90%;
      height: 100px;
      color: white;
      justify-content: center;
      justify-self: center;
      display: flex;

    } 
    .naarticket {
      color: white;
    }
   
    #blok-container-aanmaakform {
      background-color: #2d3e56;
      margin-top: 560px;
      width: 100%;
    } 
    #blok-container-overview {
      background-color: #2d3e56;
      margin-top: 1100px;
      width: 100%;
      color: white;
    } 
    #blok-container-faq {
      background-color: #2d3e56;
      margin-top: 180px;
      width: 100%;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    } 
    #blok-container-admin-tickets {
    background-color: #2d3e56;
       position: absolute;
       margin-top: 820px;
       width: 90%;
      //  overflow:scroll; 
       min-height: 400px;
       color: white;
      
    }
#cat-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'item1 item2 item3';
  margin-top: 450px;
  z-index: 70;
}
#telefonie {
grid-area: item1;
}
#website {
grid-area: item2;
}
#ict {
grid-area: item3;
}
grid-area: alletickets;
    .textfield {
     
      width: 97.5%;
      height: 200px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      background-color:#2d3e56 ;
      border-right: none;
      border-left: none;
      border-top: none;
      border-bottom: solid grey 1px;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    .verwerkknoppen {
      margin-top: 5px;
      color: white;
    }

    #flex-container {
      display: flex;
      border-bottom: solid grey 1px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
    #bijlageinfo {
      float: right;
      margin-left: 100px;
      overflow:scroll; 
      height:85px;
      min-width: 400px;
    }
    form {
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
    #overview-reply-textarea {
      width: 90%;
      height: 50px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      background-color:#2d3e56 ;
      border-right: none;
      border-left: none;
      border-top: none;
      border-bottom: solid grey 1px;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    #berichten {
      overflow:scroll; height:700px;
    }

    .velden {
      width: 97.5%;
      margin-left: 10px;
      background-color:#2d3e56 ;
      border-right: none;
      border-left: none;
      border-top: none;
      border-bottom: solid grey 1px;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 24px;
      
    }
    #blok-container {
      width: 350px;
     
    }
    
    #blok-container-register {
      width: 350px;
      margin-top: -40px;
       
      
    }
    #flexa-logo {
      width: 150px;
      justify-content: center;
      justify-self: center;
    }
    #flexa-logo-reg {
      width: 150px;
      justify-content: center;
      justify-self: center;
      margin-top: 200px;
      
    }
    #flexa-logo3 {
      display: none;
    }
    #lichaam {
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 500px;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    #lichaam2 {
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 30px;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    
    }
    .voorwaarde-tekst {
      color: white;
      
    }
    .voorwaarde-link {
      color: white;
      text-decoration-line: underline !important;
    }
    .submitknop {
      background-color: grey;
      color: white;
      width: 140px;
      height: 50px;
      border: none;
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-left: 100px;
      margin-top: 2px;


    }
    .aanmeldtekst {
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }
#register {
  color: white;
  text-decoration-line: underline !important;
}
table, th, td {
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: solid grey 1px;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
}
th {
  text-align: left;
}
#tabel {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
  /*deactivatie van scrollbar*/

  #ticket2::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
  #berichten::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
  }

  //css voor mobile + desktop menu
  body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
  }
  
  a {
    color: #000;
  }
  
  /* header */
  
  .header {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  
  .header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  .header li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .header li a:hover,
  .header .menu-btn:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
  }
  
  .header .logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  /* menu */
  
  .header .menu {
    clear: both;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
  }
  
  /* menu icon */
  
  .header .menu-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 28px 20px;
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon {
    background: #333;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    position: relative;
    transition: background .2s ease-out;
    width: 18px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    background: #333;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
    top: 5px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    top: -5px;
  }
  
  /* menu btn */
  
  .header .menu-btn {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
    max-height: 240px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
    top: 0;
  }
  
  /* 48em = 768px */
  
  @media (min-width: 48em) {
    .header li {
      float: left;
    }
    .header li a {
      padding: 20px 30px;
    }
    .header .menu {
      clear: none;
      float: right;
      max-height: none;
    }
    .header .menu-icon {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

Here's the application in a screenshot,
as you can see in the first screenshot we haven't recieved a new ticket yet

[click for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT6n3.png)

in the next screenshot we have recieved a ticket and it creates automatically margin on top..
[click for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Nnc.png)

and again after recieving another ticket, it generated more margin on top
[Click for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2tJ5.png)

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Right now, this is bascially just a big code dump. Please explain what _you_ have done so far to try and locate where the problem might lie.

Comment: And write valid HTML to begin with. `<table><div class='ticket'><tr>` - you can not insert a `div` at that position between `table` and `tr`. And same thing with `</tr><BR><BR></div>`, that is also invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The invalid HTML you are creating is causing your problem here.

This isn’t an actual `margin` in a CSS sense - it is those `br` element you placed in a position where they are not allowed.

Your code, reduced to the necessary bits, is basically

```
<table>
<div class='ticket'><tr><th>foobar</th></tr><BR><BR></div>
<div class='ticket'><tr><th>foobar</th></tr><BR><BR></div>
<div class='ticket'><tr><th>foobar</th></tr><BR><BR></div>
</table>
```

If you use your browser’s element inspector to see what DOM it has created based on that, you will likely see something like the following (this is from Chrome, but other HTML5 compatible browsers should handle this pretty much the same):

```
<div class="ticket"></div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="ticket"></div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="ticket"></div>
<br>
<br>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><th>foobar</th></tr>
<tr><th>foobar</th></tr>
<tr><th>foobar</th></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So, you need to fix your broken HTML here.

Comment: i removed the <br><br>'s and the problem is fixed. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider.

Have you check you html rendered for php error ?
You can do that with Firefox / Chrome / Opera / Safari "Inspect Element" and search for 'php error'

Sometimes my page rendered out of align because I have php error rendered  within HTML page

Comment: Cbroe answered it :) i placed 2 <br><br>'s in every result.. i was still sleeping when programming that part haha. Thx for your time do :)